# JPG Image extension not inserting into Custom table of wp

Tags: images, database

I've created a custom table on database and I need to upload image from my template page member. In this page I've done all the codings. I'm able to insert data but stuck on the image insert. I can get the file name but unable to get the extension.

Here is my inserting code of my template file.

```
$tmpfile = explode(".", $_FILES['image']['name']);
$newfile = round(microtime(true)) . '.' . end($tmpfile);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], ABSPATH . '/wp-content/themes/themename/inc/images/' . $newfile);

$sql = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("INSERT INTO members(member_image) VALUES (%s)", $newfile));
```

The above code shows the field value without extension as: https://prnt.sc/mirab5

Here is my html form field:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control">
 </form>
```

All other text fields are inserted but only image can't be derived with extension. I can't figure out the problem. I've also tried by adding .jpg extension but it didn't work.

Comment: Your screenshot does not work and needs to be uploaded somewhere public. Are you saying the image upload itself does not work (i.e. there is no file in that directory), that the database entry is missing the .jpg extension, or both?

Comment: Yes, there is no file in directory. I mean move_uploaded_file is not working. I can only get random file name in database as https://prnt.sc/mir8aa
and the file extension is also missing.

Comment: You may have 2 issues. First, you need to upload images to the uploads directory, not the theme directory, as the uploads dir should have different file permissions. Second, it doesn't look like the initial upload is working at all. May be a server setting. Above all this can you add a php line,   var_dump($_FILES);  , submit an image on the page again and paste the output? It may just be an empty array like [] or it may have a bunch of info in it.

Comment: It shows as: array(0)

Comment: Okay, so that is the root problem. There's no extension to save in the first place because there is no file. This is now much more of a server issue than a WordPress one. There's a lot of server configuration variables and I'm going to let someone else jump in and/or recommend you post on general stackoverflow.